# Remove old/unused provisioning profiles from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode3.2

I initially had one beta tester for my ios app. Eventually the number has gradually increased to 4. So from time to time I have kept on modifying the same provisioning profile. On the website, it shows a single provisioning profile, thats just fine.

But in xcode, it is showing all those profiles which I have used, How can I remove them from xcode so that only the latest one is displayed(as on the website).

Xcode: 3.2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning profiles, Now you delete provisioning by right click and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.1.1
In the Menu Window ==> Devices ==> Select Device ==> Click Mouse Right Button ==> Show Provisioning Profiles

You can delete unused profiles in that menu.